# Print the title from a txt file from the given word

Tags: python

I have a txt file with the following info:

- `545524---Python foundation---Course---https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/100x100/647442_5c1f.jpg---Outsourcing Development Work: Learn My Proven System To Hire Freelance Developers`
- `Another line with the same format but different info and continue....`

Here on line 1, `Python foundation` is the course title. If a user has input "foundation" how do I print out Python foundation? It's basically printing the whole title of a course based on the given word.
I can use something like:

```
input_text = 'foundation'
file1 = open("file.txt", "r")
readfile = file1.read()
if input_text in readfile: 
    #This prints only foundation keyword not the whole title
```

Comment: You might have a look at similar udemy-text-file parsing question from user _Tech_: [find title from txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72091205/find-title-from-txt-file-using-user-input-id-and-add-them-to-a-list).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your input file has multiple lines separated by enters in this format:
`<Course-id>---<Course-name>---Course---<Course-image-link>---<Desc>`

```
input_text = 'foundation'
file1 = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    book_title_pattern = r'---([\w\d\s_\.,;:()]+)---'
    match = re.search(book_title_pattern, line)
    if match:
        matched_title = match.groups(1)[0]
        if input_text in matched_title:
            print(matched_title)
```

Comment: Yup that was not my mistake, I just copied that name from question body :D

Comment: What will happen if there's a line in the file that doesn't conform to the expected pattern?

Comment: Consider checking for the title only in idx 1 of the split and not the whole line. There could be other things in the line where the word appears and is not relevant. Also, match on lower-case input & field 1, to make the search case-insensitive.

Comment: Tnx for your tips, I updated my solution to address your issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match `---Course name---` using `---([a-zA-Z ]+)---`. This will give you all the course names. Then you can check for the `user_input` in each course and print the course name if you find `user_input` in it.:

```
import re

user_input = 'foundation'
file1 = open("file.txt", "r")
readfile = file1.read()
course_name = re.findall('---([a-zA-Z ]+)---', readfile)
for course in course_name:
    if user_input in course: #Then check for 'foundation' in course_name
        print(course)
```

Output:

```
Python foundation
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just wondering, what if I've to search the title based on the id?

Comment: @Techmaster Multiple questions are usually not encouraged in comments. Kindly ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Get the key value that you're searching for. User input perhaps or we'll hard-code it here for demo' purposes.

Open the file and read one line at a time. Use RE to parse the line looking for a specific pattern. Check that we've actually found a token matching the RE criterion then check if it contains the 'key' value. Print result as appropriate.

```
import re
key = 'foundation'
with open('input.txt') as infile:
    for line in map(str.strip, infile):
        if (t := re.findall('---([a-zA-Z\s]+)---', line)) and key in t[0]:
            print(t[0])
```

Comment: Thank you. Just curious what if I've to search the title using id?

Comment: @Techmaster What id do you mean? Do you mean the 545524 in your example? If that's the case then you can just split on '-' and it'll be the first token. Or use a different RE to identify sequences of numbers

Comment: I mean if the user input 545524, it should print out the course title Python foundation and any other title recorded on that id (545524) from the txt file. I was thinking of using re? split function works for me too but not sure where to start