# Find title from txt file using user input id and add them to a list

Tags: python

I have a txt file with the following info:

- 545524---Python foundation---Course---https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/100x100/647442_5c1f.jpg---Outsourcing
  Development Work: Learn My Proven System To Hire Freelance Developers
- Another line with the same format but different info(might have the same id)and continue....

Here on line 1, Python foundation is the course title. If a user has input id 545524 how do I print out course title Python foundation? It's basically printing the whole title of a course based on the given input id. I tried using following but got stuck:

```
input = ''
with open(r"sample.txt") as data: 
 read_data = data.read() 
 id_search = re.findall(r'regex, read_data) 
 title_search = re.findall(r'regex', read_data) 
 for id_input in id_search: 
  if input in id_input: 
   #Then I got stuck
```

I need to print all the titles based on that id. and finally add them to a list. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Would it be possible just to use .split() and the id?

Comment: Sure but how do I do that?

Comment: `txt = "545524---Python foundation---Course---https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/100x100/647442_5c1f.jpg---Outsourcing Development Work: Learn My Proven System To Hire Freelance Developers545524---Python foundation---Course---https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/100x100/647442_5c1f.jpg---Outsourcing Development Work: Learn My Proven System To Hire Freelance Developers"                                                           
txt = txt.split("545524")                                                                                                                           
print(txt)`

Comment: What you did is completely different from what I was asking but thank you for trying tho

Comment: As in once you have that, you can just .split() it again for --- and then grab the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Kemmisch is on the money here, you can just split the whole string on the `---` and assign each separate element to it's own variable

**somefile.txt**

```
545524---Python foundation---Course---https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/100x100/647442_5c1f.jpg---Outsourcing Development Work: Learn My Proven System To Hire Freelance Developers
12345---Not Python foundation---Ofcourse---https://some.url/here---This is something else
```

**main.py**

```py
with open('somefile.txt') as infile:
    data = infile.read().splitlines() # os agnostic, and removes end of lines characters

for line in data:
    idnr, title, dunno_what_this_is, url, description = line.split('---')
    print('--------------------')
    print(idnr)
    print(title)
    print(dunno_what_this_is)
    print(url)
    print(description)
```

**output**

```
--------------------
545524
Python foundation
Course
https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/100x100/647442_5c1f.jpg
Outsourcing Development Work: Learn My Proven System To Hire Freelance Developers
--------------------
12345
Not Python foundation
Ofcourse
https://some.url/here
This is something else
```

**EDIT**

---

Now if you want to search for a specific ID you can just use an if statement. Sample below uses the same `somefile.txt`.

```py
id_input = input("Provide an ID to search for: ")


with open('somefile.txt') as infile:
    data = infile.read().splitlines() # os agnostic, and removes end of lines characters

for line in data:
    idnr, title, dunno_what_this_is, url, description = line.split('---')
    if idnr == id_input:
        print('--------------------')
        print(idnr)
        print(title)
        print(dunno_what_this_is)
        print(url)
        print(description)
```

**output**

```
Provide an ID to search for: 12345
--------------------
12345
Not Python foundation
Ofcourse
https://some.url/here
This is something else
```